# Getting dimension of a device

Tags: android, xml

Is there a way to get *width and height* of an android device and use them in the `XML` file?
my goal is to make a dynamic application both for small and big screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the height and width as fill parent. Then it will take the whole device screen height and width.

Like this:

```
android:height="fill_parent"
android:width="fill_parent"
```

**Edited:**

If you want to use like 20%. Then make the `android:weightSum` of parent layout to 5.0 and child parent `layout:weight="1.0"` like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5.0" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#0000FF" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#00FF00" >
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

It will set the layout fit to every screen size.

Comment: i want to use the numbers, e.g 20% width of the screen

Comment: @Branky see the edited portion.

Answer (score 2):

u can do it programatically though and use in code.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Display mDisplay = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width  = mDisplay.getWidth();
int height = mDisplay.getHeight();
```

This way you get the screen size.

Comment: but i can't use them in XML file.

Comment: You can't quey screen size in xml

Comment: there is no alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Create folders inside res folder by the name of values-mdpi, values-hdpi, and so on. Android will load the correct file at runtime. You can create many types of file for reference
 [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate display size using following code . you can find it [Here- get screen size in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

and then Make different layout according to your sizes . It is Explained [Here- resize-your-image-according-to-screen-sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626302/resize-your-image-according-to-screen-sizes)

Hope This will help you