# Android: Set Image/Icon according to "Screen Size" not "Screen Density"(dpi's)

Tags: android, image, screen-size, image-size, screen-density

I am working on a Layout having 14 Icons in a screen. I created **9-patch** images for all icons and added them in corresponding folders: **MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI,XXHDPI,XXXHDPI**,it's working fine.
I tested on a few devices, as we know images are added and selected to display accordingly **"Screen Density" not "Screen Size"**.

I used **ScreenLayout_Size_Mask** to get actual Screen size category.(ScreenLayout_Size_SMALL, ScreenLayout_Size_NORMAL, ScreenLayout_Size_LARGE,ScreenLayout_Size_XLARGE) I am retrieving Screen Size and Density of the screen. For ref:[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/how-to-determine-device-screen-size-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-usin)

---

For Device:

***Nexus7(1200 x 1920 px ~323 ppi):***

> ScreenLayout_Size_LARGE and Density is XHIGH

***Samsung Galaxy Grand-2(720 x 1280 px ~280 ppi):***

> ScreenLayout_Size_NORMAL and Density is
>   XHIGH.

Though there is a big difference in their "Screen Sizes" still their **dpi's are same(XHIGH) so selected icon images for both device are of same density(XHDPI) only,** which actually should not be done, as icons will be inflated of bigger size comparatively on small screen devices(Galaxy Grand-2) which seems messy.

According to android standards we can add image resources for multiple Screen Density only and not according to Screen size.

One option I got is *set ImageView size in ratio with screen size*, but there are 14 icons in layout,how can I get proper ratio size for all ImageViews?

Other approach I found is to *do programmatically like this:*

1. Get Actual Screen size using ScreenLayout_Size_Mask
2. Add different images with different name for (small,normal,large,xlarge).

Is there any proper way to do so ? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626302/resize-your-image-according-to-screen-sizes